# Button fixed to the bottom of the page expands child div on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div that expands on click and I made that work so far. Trouble is that I need the button to stay fixed at the bottom of the page and at the end of the page, it stays on top of the footer (above .bottom and footer). How can I do that?

**HTML**

```
<section></section>

<aside>
  <div class="button"></div>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="bar">
    <div class="close">X</div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-h-c-353-480-3.jpg"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-h-c-353-480-2.jpg"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-h-c-353-480-2.jpg">
   </div>
  </div>

</aside>

<div class="bottom"></div>
<footer></footer>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 20%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 1300px;
  left: -20%;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

.close {
  color: white;
  background: black;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  float: right;
}

aside {
  position: relative;
  width: 1024px;
}

.container{
  left: 20%;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}

footer {
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.bottom {
  background-color: pink;
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

section {
  height: 700px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.bar').hide();

$('.button').click(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    top: -500});
  $('.bar').show();
  $('.container').animate({
    top: -450});
});

  $('.close').click(function(){
    $('.button').animate({
    top: -50});
    $('.bar').slideDown().fadeOut(500);
    $('.container').animate({
    top: 0});
  });
```

**CodePen:**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CFDcL

Comment: You mean something like that http://jsfiddle.net/z51yrofs/3/ ?

Comment: You should use css to do this animation

Answer (score 0):

Add for your button:

```
bottom: -50px;  /* instead of 0 */
z-index: 10000; /* just cause footer is 9999 :) */
```